# APS Model Derivative API flex token usage

Tags: autodesk-forge

Hi i am creating a little app that extracts metadate/parameters from a NWC/NWD/RVT file and analyses the parameter data.

Steps:
Create a Bucket
Stranslate a file to svf
Extract meta data.

I wonder how many flex tokens it takes to convert a file to svf then extract the metadata/parameters.

I read that a complex task is 0.5 tokens and a simple task is 0.1 tokens.
is creating a bucket 0.1 tokens,
conversion 0.1 tokens
and meta data extraction 0.1 token each?

just trying to calculate how much it will cost per month to run a service like this.

Your help would we appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't depend per month or year, it depends on the number of files being translated. Calculate the tokens based on the number of files, then convert the tokens into currency. Tokens and cloud credits depend on the country, please select your country from drop down and then calculate.
https://aps.autodesk.com/pricing